# Git-related Issues uploading to Heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku, npm

I have exactly the same issue as User daffodils.  When uploaded to heroku the app fails with a message "npm ERR! missing script: start" But I don't have a start command in my package.json and I do have "web : node app.js" in my Procfile

I don't have a start in my package.json file and the same file worked ok for another similar app on heroku:

```
{
  "name": "tBlogv3withdb",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "engines": {
    "node": "13.12.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.10"
  }
}
```

User Daffodils said "I dropped the repo and re-init solved it." - what does this mean exactly?

Comment: I think re-init caused to have start script in package.json. Solution to your problem might be adding  `start:node app.js` in scripts of package.json.

Comment: Thank  you for your suggestion.  I fixed the issue by deleting the repository on heroku, deleting the .git file in my application, renaming the app and creating a new repository.  This is how Daffodil fixed the same problem he was having.

I also made a minor change to the Procfile: It was web : node app.js and i changed it to web: node app.js (deleting the space before the colon.

Anyway it now works fine :-)

Comment: So I can't answer my own question...  What a strange site this is....